# How can i remove google calendar unverified app screen?

Tags: google-oauth, google-calendar-api

Good morning.
I use google calendar API.
My program create a connection with the google calendar of multiple users.
From each user, i have their credential.json, but when the app start the first time show the browser quickstart confirm. How i can skip this step?
Thanks anticipated

Comment: Your users should NOT be giving you their credential.json file (from google developer consonsole).  This file should be created by you the developer, and should not be shared with anyone.   Each user should be logging in to your app no more.   Once you have completed development of your application you should apply for verification at then the unverified app screen will go away.

Comment: Exscuse me. My program need to use API for look in more calendars (of more poeople). If i undestand, i need to add the credentials.json of people in my google console under API and services - > credetials? Thanks anticipated

Comment: You need to go to google developer console. create credietnals for our application.  Then request that each user run your application when they run it your application will then have access to their data.  Each application needs only once set of client credentials created on google  developer console.    Please edit your question and include your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have seriously misunderstood how Oauth2 works.

You the developer goes to Google developer console and registers your application.  If you will be requesting data from other users you will need to create Oauth2 credentials this will give you  credeitnals.json file used by your application to request authorization of a user.

When each of your users runs your application they will be requested to consent to your application authorizing their data.  If they do you will be granted an access token which gives you access to their data, this access token will expire after one hour.  If you have also request offline access then you will also have a refresh token.  If you store this refresh token some place then you will be able to access the users data when ever you need to by using it to request a new access token.

As for the unverified app screen,  when you create your application it is basically in developer state, this is so that you can build and test your application. When you are ready to go to production you can request that your application be [verified](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en) by google

Once your app has been verified the unverified app screen will stop showing up.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Exscuse me, and my english. I have created credential.json for each user from each google developer console (of my users). This is ok. I have the files credential json. But the problem is that i want to run standalone this program. If i undestand, this is not planned. My problem is that my program must run standalone for syncronize events through more users (with google calendar api) without interaction

Comment: You do **NOT** create a credentials.json for each user from Google developer console.  you create a single credentials.json for your application.   You cant run it without user interaction unless you have gsuite and can use a service account.  Your users must grant your application access to their data.  credentials.json does not grant you access to any data.